# How do I resolve indexing error when trying to replace duplicate values in a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, duplicates

I have a pandas data frame in the following format:

```
Date            PlantFlow   PlantChrome KXRunTime   XE1 XE2         XE3         XE4         XE5      XE6        
1/1/2021 0:01   485998857   24571431    108977      0   17106889    15869791    32957935    8699419     22887911    
1/2/2021 0:00   486702763   24600740    109217      0   17157255    15920161    32993915    8741919     22928438    
1/3/2021 0:00   487406859   24630055    109457      0   17207650    15970564    33029915    8784259     22968983    
1/4/2021 0:00   488110394   24659347    109697      0   17258047    16020968    33065913    8826332     23009485            
1/5/2021 0:00   488833064   24689436    109937      0   17308451    16071374    33101920    8868566     23049956            
1/6/2021 0:00   489565728   24719943    110177      0   17358855    16121780    33137929    8911273     23090415
1/7/2021 0:00   490298497   24750469    110417      0   17409291    16172191    33173938    8953880     23130905
1/8/2021 0:00   491031226   24780977    110657      0   17459695    16222596    33209945    8996583     23171404
1/9/2021 0:00   491764013   24811487    110897      0   17510099    16273002    33245951    9039404     23211905
```

I have a python function for replacing duplicate column values with `0` but keeping the first:

```
def dups_to_zero(df):
       
    df = df.mask(df.duplicated(df.iloc[:, 1:], keep='first'),0)
    
    return df
```

The desired output is a data frame as follows:

```
Date        PlantFlow   PlantChrome KXRunTime       XE1 XE2         XE3         XE4         XE5     XE6     
1/1/2021 0:01   485998857   24571431    108977      0   17106889    15869791    32957935    8699419     22887911    
1/2/2021 0:00   486702763   24600740    109217      0   17157255    15920161    32993915    8741919     22928438    
1/3/2021 0:00   487406859   24630055    109457      0   17207650    15970564    0           8784259     22968983    
1/4/2021 0:00   488110394   24659347    109697      0   17258047    16020968    33065913    8826332     23009485            
1/5/2021 0:00   488833064   24689436    109937      0   17308451    16071374    33101920    8868566     23049956            
1/6/2021 0:00   489565728   24719943    110177      0   17358855    16121780    33137929    8911273     23090415
1/7/2021 0:00   490298497   24750469    110417      0   17409291    16172191    33173938    8953880     23130905
1/8/2021 0:00   491031226   24780977    110657      0   17459695    16222596    33209945    8996583     23171404
1/9/2021 0:00   491764013   24811487    110897      0   17510099    16273002    33245951    9039404     23211905
```

When calling the function (`test = dups_to_zero(df)`), I get a key error about indexing that I can not seem to resolve. This seems so basic but is obviously difficult.

[image]

Any help or tips for resolving this error would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you try replacing the following line: ```df = df.mask(df.duplicated(df.iloc[:, 1:].columns, keep='first'),0)```

Comment: That resolves the error, but the duplicates are not replaced with zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the entire function to this below which worked:

```
def dups_to_zero(df):
    
    is_duplicate = df.apply(pd.Series.duplicated, axis=0)
    df = df.where(~is_duplicate, 0)
    
    return df
```